# Delete rows in a data frame that have a specific value in a corresponding row of another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, indicator, grepl

I have two data frames.

The first holds my actual data, lets call it **data**. The second serves as an indicator matrix, which is constructed using a if-else statement which checks for the occurrence of a row of values containing at least 1 or 2, lets call it **indic**.

Here is an example:

```
col1<-c(1,3,1,3,2)
col2<-c(3,4,2,3,"")
col3<-c(1,3,"","","")
col4<-c(2,"","","","")

data<-data.frame(cbind(col1,col2,col3,col4))

> data
  col1 col2 col3 col4
     1    3    1    2
     3    4    3     
     1    2          
     3    3          
     2
```

The rows of **data** must contain *at least a 1 or a 2*, so here is my function:

```
remove<-function(x){

  if (((x[1] == "1") | (x[1] == "2")) | ((x[2] == "1") | (x[2] == "2"))
      | ((x[3] == "1") | (x[3] == "2")) | ((x[4] == "1") | (x[4] == "2"))){
    return(0)
  }

else{
  return(1)
}
}

indic<-data.frame(apply(data,1,remove))

> indic
        y
1       0
2       1
3       0
4       1
5       0
```

From looking at **data**, row 2 and row 4 do not contain at least a 1 or a 2, which is confirmed by **indic**.

I would like to remove rows 2 and 4 in **data**, which correspond to rows 2 and 4 in **indic**.  I have already tried the following:

```
finalMatrix<-class(array)

for(i in 1:nrow(indic)){
  if (indic[i,1] == "1"){
    finalMatrix = data[-i,]
  }
  else{
    data[i,] = data[i,]
  }
}
```

However, my output is something like this:

```
> finalMatrix
  col1 col2 col3 col4
    1    3    1    2
    3    4    3     
    1    2                  
    2
```

Which effectively eliminates the fourth row ONLY.  I think it might have something to do with the fact that I must make a new dataframe after each iteration, but then the problem is that the iteration length changes.

Wondering if I am on the right track with my code... any suggestions would be lovely.  I have been overthinking this for some time.

-Soph

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want something like `finalMatrix <- data[indic != "1", ]`?

Comment: `finalMatrix <- data[which(indic==0),]` would be also possible in this case

Comment: Why not just `data[rowSums(data=="1" | data=="2")>0,]`? You are not using vectorization properly and that `for` loop is very bad efficiency-wise. Also, there seems no reason to coerce your values to `character`; use `NA` for missing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to generate a TRUE/FALSE vetor instead of your indic vector, which contains 0/1. This makes the final filtering more obvious.

```
> data
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    1    3    1    2
2    3    4    3     
3    1    2          
4    3    3          
5    2
```

The use of `any` will give you easy access to the row's content of `1` or `2`. A second `any` will tell you, if one of the two conditions was met. The `apply()` the runs through all the rows, if the second parameter is set to 1.

```
indic <- apply(data, 1, function(row) {
    any(c(any(row == 1), any(row == 2)))
})


> indic
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

> data[indic,]
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    1    3    1    2
3    1    2          
5    2
```

As the title of your question suggests the indic-vector could be also applied to another data frame, but here it's important to watch out for the data frame and indic-vector having the same dimensions or aiming for vector recycling.

Picking up @nicola's suggestion to use vectorization.

```
data[rowSums(data=="1" | data=="2")>0,]
```

This would do the job most efficiently sparing loops and creating `indic`. Although the TRUE/FALSE vector emitted from `rowSums(data=="1" | data=="2")>0` could still be saved in a variable.